# ES6 AngularJS directive <> service communication

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I think i have a scope problem with js. Please take a look to my code below.
This is my AngularJS example in es6. I compile the code to es5 with grunt browserify.

If i call my example i got the error:
**TypeError: this.gatewayServiceGet is not a function
    at ChainsDirective.loadChains [as chainsServiceLoadChains]**

I check it and find out that **this** in **loadChains** is not the same **this** than in the constructor.

What can i do?

This is my app.js

```
'use strict';

import AppController from './appController.js';
import ChainsDirective from './components/chains/chains.directive.js';
import ChainsService from './components/chains/chains.service.js';
import GatewayService from './components/common/gateway/gateway.service.js';

angular
    .module('SalesCockpit', ['ui.router', 'ui.grid'])
    .config($stateProvider => {
        $stateProvider
            .state('chains', {
                url: '/chains',
                templateUrl: 'components/chains/chains.html'
            })
            .state('chainDetail', {
                url: '/chain/{chainId:int}/detail',
                templateUrl: 'components/chain-detail/chain-detail.html'
            })
        ;

    })
    .controller('AppController', AppController)
    .service('chainsService', ChainsService)
    .service('gatewayService', GatewayService)
    .directive('chains', ChainsDirective);
```

This is my chain directive

```
export default function ChainsDirective() {
    class ChainsDirective {

        /*@ngInject*/
        constructor(chainsService, $state) {
            this.chainsServiceLoadChains = chainsService.loadChains;
            this.gridOptions = {
                enableColumnMenus: false,
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        name: 'id',
                        visible: false
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'name',
                        displayName: 'Kette',
                        cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a ng-click="grid.appScope.openDetail(row.entity.id)">{{row.entity.name}}</a></div>'
                    }
                ]
            };
            this.$stateGo = $state.go;
            this.fetch();
        }

        /**
         * @param int chainId
         */
        openDetail(chainId) {
            this.$stateGo('chainDetail', {chainId})
        }

        fetch() {
            return this.chainsServiceLoadChains().then(data => {
                this.gridOptions.data = data
            })
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="chains" ui-grid="gridOptions" external-scopes="$scope" class="grid"></div>',
        controller: ChainsDirective,
        controllerAs: 'chains'
    }
}
```

This is my chain servie

```
export default class ChainsService {

    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor(gatewayService) {
        this.gatewayServiceGet = gatewayService.get;
    }

    /**
     * @returns Promise
     */
    loadChains() {
        return this.gatewayServiceGet('loadChains');
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the code is being cross compiled and not ran in something like Edge. Can you post the translated code? I'm particularly interested in how the class gets translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, this has nothing to do with ECMAScript 2015. JavaScript always worked that way.

---

The value of `this` depends on how the function is **called**. So if you call it as

```
this.chainsServiceLoadChains()
```

`this` inside `chainsServiceLoadChains` will refer to what is before the `.`, which is `this` that refers to the `ChainsDirective` instance.

One solution would be to **bind** the `this` value of the function to a specific value:

```
this.chainsServiceLoadChains = chainsService.loadChains.bind(chainsService);
```

Now it doesn't matter anymore how the function is called, `this` will always refer to `chainsService`.

Learn more about `this`:

- [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)